# Managing databases with Java desktop applications

Tags: java, mysql

Sorry for the long explanation here but here goes:

As a personal project, I've toyed with making a server management tool for game server hosts.
All of the server hosts use MySQL servers and they're all separate servers.

So:
Is there a java IDE or java library I can use for creating a java desktop app that can communicate with MySQL databases?

More specifically: I need to have clients use a login form to specify the IP address, port, username and password. When they hit connect, the java application sends the login information to the server specified, authenticates and connects.
Then the user can execute T-SQL by simply clicking buttons on a form.

I'm looking for something similar to what I've recently achieved in C# with the MySQL connector for .NET.
But I can't find anything anywhere on something like this, is it just impossible or am I being an idiot? haha. Cheers guys.

Comment: This is all built into the netbeans and exclipse platforms, you could implement on top of either, yes...?

Comment: I'll give it a look into, but from what I seen of netbeans, you need to specify the database first.
Again, taking a look.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for a JDBC driver? It should be *Connector/J*. (Seeing as you mention Connector/.NET.) A JDBC tutorial might also come in handy. Or do you want an equivalent of your existing *application* that uses the .NET driver?

Comment: I'll grab the JDBC Driver and Eclipse and see what I can pull together in there too.
Thanks to both of you. Two good starting points for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve login functionality providing you are going to use swing, use [JXloginPane](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXLoginPane.html) it contains all what you described out of the box. Regarding db, you can use [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)